# How can I save the kidnapped daughter while keeping my money?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

In the side quest "A Daughter Ransomed" is there a way to save the girl, keep your money, and kill the bandits?

Comment: needs a spoiler tag?

Comment: added, not that it's really spoiling much as it's a side quest and a short one at that.

Comment: Also who edited the question it's not 'my' daughter it's someone else daughter... isn't it?

Comment: If it's not actually a spoiler, then you won't need the "spoiler" tag. And if it isn't your daughter, then you should also revert that as well. You can see the revision history by clicking on the timestamp next to "edited".

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity why was the game title and quest title removed from the title. the title is almost too generic to be useful now, don't you think?

Comment: @Jack: The game is already mentioned in the tags and the quest name is mentioned in the body.  I'd personally keep the quest name somewhere in the title, but that's just me.  *(shrug)*

Comment: Removing xbox tag, cos da exists on other platforms too

Comment: OK due to popular demand (well the comment got 2 votes anyway) I put the Game and Quest Title back in the question title. I put the game in because there is not an 'Awakening' tag yet. Yeah the 'Expansions' tag should cover it but there is a lot of DLC for this title.

Comment: I was the one who edited the title. Yes, I probably made a mistake with whose daughter it was, but as mentioned on other questions as well, adding the game in the title is redundant

Comment: There you go, based on this Meta discussion, I highly recommend you to edit the title to remove the quest and game name. As the game is in the tags and the quest is in the question

Comment: There's a [meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/821/question-with-vague-title) about this. Editing the title back to conform to site policy.

Comment: fair enough. Personally i don't agree, but I understand the reasoning and the legacy behind it. Not a fight worth fighting at this point.

Comment: This should be on money.stackexchange.com ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes walk up to them and use intimidate or persuasion. Tell them they have to send the girl to you first then you'll give them the money. Once they do that you just kill them/pay them.

[Listing at the wiki](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/A_Daughter_Ransomed)

Can someone editing the questions tags and mark it as Dragon Age: Origins - Awakening. As it's a quest in the expansion not the original.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's too long to fit as a tag. What would you suggest as a proper abbreviation?

Comment: How's that?  8 )

Comment: Or dragonage-awakening people will normally know it's the expansion, doesn't need the origins there